# Why do these two methods give different answers? MOMENT OF INERTIA

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

A question and a figure are shown in the image below.

MOI—MOMENT OF INERTIA

COM—CENTER OF MASS

[image]

*In my attempts to answer this question, I discovered two approaches:*

***The first method entails the following steps:***
Using the **parallel axis theorem**, you can calculate the moment of inertia due to disc **about the given axis**(as we know the MOI about the axis passing through the Center of mass of the disc): *MOI due to disc = (MR^2)/2 + M(4R^2).*

Add it to the MOI offered by the Rod about that point, i.e., *M(4R^2)/12*
(which is also equal to the MOI (by rod only) about the Axis passing through the COM of the rod) to get the total MOI,

and the answer came out to be **MOI = 29(MR^2)/6**

***2nd approach:***

I calculated the COM of the whole system, which came out to be at R distance from the center of the disc (at the middle of the line joining the centers of masses of these objects).

Now, **using parallel axis theorem** on the disc's and rod's center of mass and the axis passing through this COM, I calculated the **total MOI about the axis passing through this COM of the system** (which I found to be easier).

The MOI about the axis passing through the COM of the entire system was calculated to be

*MOI = 17(MR^2)/6*

Finally, I used parallel axis theory once again(between this axis and the given perpendicular axis) to arrive at the final answer, which was:

(by adding MR^2), the moment of inertia about the given perpendicular axis, which turned out to be

**total MOI about the given axis = 23(MR^2)/6**

As you can see, the two answers are quite different. Despite the fact that they appear to be similar, the answer obtained by the first method is correct, while the answer obtained by the second is not. Why is that?

I've followed all the rules.

NOTE
Anyone can make changes to the equations to make them easier to understand.

MOI—MOMENT OF INERTIA

COM—CENTER OF MASS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final step in the second method requires the total mass of the system (2M)$R^2$